# Which one is correct- '1980's Wimbledon' or 'Wimbledon of 1980'?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-choice

I stuck to one point while writing a blog. Basically, I wrote ...

> 'This technology is used in tennis since **1980's Wimbledon**.

But then...

> This technology is used in tennis since **Wimbledon of 1980**.'

...also looks fine to me.

My questions are: Which one of this is correct? If both are correct then which style is more preferable?

I also welcome suggestions to improve the given sentence.

Comment: Personally, I'd use *This technology has been used in tennis since Wimbledon **in** 1980,* but grammatically speaking both your references to Wimbledon are fine. It's your use of ***is used*** rather than ***has been used*** that marks the text as having been produced by a non-native speaker. In practice I suspect many writers would be more likely to go for a more radical rephrasing though; *This technology **was first introduced** at Wimbledon in 1980,* for example.

Answer (score 1):

> This technology *has been* used in tennis **since 1980's Wimbledon**.

"1980's Wimbledon" could refer to any year 1980-1989, not specifically 1980. It is like "since the 1980's".

> This technology *has been* used in tennis since Wimbledon of 1980.

I would reword this to:

> This technology *has been* used in tennis **at Wimbledon since 1980**.